# How to arrange a transparent JTextPane in other components with disabled highlighting

Tags: java, swing, transparency, highlight, jtextpane

Could someone give me a hint on how to display a transparent `JTextPane` that is the child of other components such as a `JScrollPane` and a `JPanel`, please. I've used an `AlphaContainer` which is available [here](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for transparency.

This is working:

```
chatTextPane = new JTextPane();
chatTextPane.setEditable(false);
chatTextPane.setHighlighter(null);
chatTextPane.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255,100));
AlphaContainer ac = new AlphaContainer(chatTextPane);   

JPanel chatPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
chatPanel.setOpaque(false);
chatPanel.add(ac);
```

It looks like this:

[image: transparent JTextPane]

However if I wrap it into a non-opaque `JScrollPane`, it is not transparent anymore. And if I put the `JScrollPane` in an `AlphaContainer`, highlighting is enabled again (and buggy):

```
chatTextPane = new JTextPane();
chatTextPane.setEditable(false);
chatTextPane.setHighlighter(null);
chatTextPane.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255,100));
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(chatTextPane);
scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
AlphaContainer ac = new AlphaContainer(scrollPane);

JPanel chatPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
chatPanel.setOpaque(false);
chatPanel.add(ac);
```

It looks like this then:

[image: broken transparent JTextPane in JScrollPane]

Finally I originally want to add it to another panel with a `JTextField` in a `BoxLayout` as well. If I try this, the `JTextField` is displayed twice: once correctly at the bottom, but also at the top (non-editable).

[image: transparent JTextPane with JTextField]

I've been trying to fix this for a couple of hours now and I'm thankful for anything.

Here's runnable code for the second example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new MyClass();
    }

    public MyClass() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                        | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(100, 0, 0, 255));

                //
                JTextPane chatTextPane = new JTextPane();
                chatTextPane.setEditable(false);
                chatTextPane.setHighlighter(null);
                chatTextPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
                chatTextPane.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255,100));
                chatTextPane.setText("testtesttesttesttesttest");
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(chatTextPane);
                scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
                AlphaContainer ac = new AlphaContainer(scrollPane);

                JPanel chatPanel = new JPanel();
                chatPanel.setOpaque(false);
                chatPanel.add(ac);              
                //
                
                frame.add(chatPanel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    private class AlphaContainer extends JComponent {
        private JComponent component;

        public AlphaContainer(JComponent component) {
            this.component = component;
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setOpaque(false);
            component.setOpaque(false);
            add(component);
        }

        /**
         * Paint the background using the background Color of the contained component
         */
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(component.getBackground());
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *However if I wrap it into a non-opaque JScrollPane, it is not transparent anymore.* - the text pane is transparent but the scrollpane is not and the viewport of the scrollpane is not transparent. Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I've uploaded runnable code of the not working example [here](https://pastebin.com/eLx75nr1)

Comment: The code should be posted in the forum here so we can see the code without following a link to another website.

Comment: I've added the code to the question

Comment: (1+) nice [mre]..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing components have a parent/child relationship. In your case it looks like:

- JFrame

  - content pane (with custom background color)

    - chat panel

      - JScrollPane

        - JViewport

          - JTextPane

Swing paints the parent components before the child components. So you want the content pane (which is opaque) to be painted first, then the "ChatPanel" (which will be semi-transparent) painted next and then all other child components to be non-opaque.

So a couple of changes:

1. The `AlphaContainer` needs to be used on the component being added to the content pane.

You do this by using:

```
//frame.add(chatPanel);
frame.add( new AlphaContainer(chatPanel) );
```

Note: the `AlphaContainer` will make the component added to it non-opaque, so you don't need to explicitly use setOpaque( false );

2. You need to make the JTextPane non-opaque (since is no loner added to the AlphaContainer).
3. You also need to make the `JViewport` non-opaque.

This is done by using:

```
scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque( false );
```

Also don't use:

```
chatTextPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
```

The scrollbars will only appear when the preferred size of the component is greater than the size of the scroll pane. If you hardcode the preferred size, then the scrollbar won't appear because the preferred size won't change as you add text to the text area.

Set the preferred size on the scroll pane.